How can I format a JavaScript date in RFC 9557 format with a time zone?
How do I format a JS Date into an RFC 9557 format with a time zone suffix, so that I can record both the exact time that something happened as well as the time zone and local time that it happened?
This format is also helpful for interoperating with java.time.ZonedDateTime or for using the upcoming JavaScript API Temporal.ZonedDateTime.
I'd like output like this:

2024-12-18T08:32:23.95+00:00[Europe/London]
2024-12-18T03:38:58.765-05:00[America/New_York]
2024-12-18T05:43:12.150+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]


Here's a function I wrote to format JS Date objects with a time zone. Sharing it here to help others.


function formatRFC9557(date, timeZone, fractionalSecondDigits = 3) {
  const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    timeZone,
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: 'numeric',
    fractionalSecondDigits: fractionalSecondDigits === 0 ? undefined : fractionalSecondDigits,
    timeZoneName: 'longOffset'
  });

  // Extract each date/time component
  const parts = formatter.formatToParts(date).filter(({ type }) => type !== 'literal');
  const obj = Object.fromEntries(parts.map(({ type, value }) => [type, value]));
  const { year, month, day, hour, minute, second, fractionalSecond, timeZoneName } = obj;

  // Intl.DateTimeFormat returns 'GMT' for UTC, so we need to normalize it to '+00:00'
  // For non-zero UTC offsets, it returns 'GMT+XX:XX' or 'GMT-XX:XX'
  const offset = timeZoneName === 'GMT' ? '+00:00' : timeZoneName.replace('GMT', '');

  const partialSeconds = fractionalSecond ? `.${fractionalSecond}` : '';
  const dateAndTime = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}:${second}${partialSeconds}`;

  return `${dateAndTime}${offset}[${timeZone}]`;
}

//Examples: 
console.log(new Date(),'\n',

formatRFC9557(new Date(), 'Asia/Tokyo')
// => '2024-12-18T05:52:45.770+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]'

,'\n',

formatRFC9557(new Date(), 'America/Los_Angeles')
// => '2024-12-18T12:54:56.633-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]'

,'\n',

formatRFC9557(new Date(), 'America/Los_Angeles', 0)
// => '2024-12-18T12:59:16-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]'

);




I made a running snippet
